# MySql create variable from sql select

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

Is there way to create variable from select ?

```
set @MY_ID = 'SELECT ID FROM TMS.MY_TABLE WHERE MY_TABLE.UNIQ_COLUMN= 2134';
```

Code above works but it just saves string:

`SELECT @MY_ID;` returns

> SELECT ID FROM TMS.MY_TABLE WHERE MY_TABLE.UNIQ_COLUMN= 2134'

I have to know this id to use it as foreign key to insert into another tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
SELECT @MY_ID := ID
FROM TMS.MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_TABLE.UNIQ_COLUMN = 2134;
```

Comment: @gstackoverflow Be sure the result can only have one record. So most likely you need to add `ORDER BY column LIMIT 1` if `MY_TABLE.UNIQ_COLUMN` not has a unique or primary key

Comment: @Raymond Nijland, thanks for reminder but as you can see I provided that I use column with name **UNIQ_COLUMN**

Comment: @gstackoverflow Ok how should i know maybe `UNIQ` meant something `unix quality` or `unix quantity` or something else like that

Answer (score 1):

The other variation would be

```
SELECT 
 ID
FROM 
 TMS.MY_TABLE
INTO @MY_ID
WHERE
 MY_TABLE.UNIQ_COLUMN = 2134
```

Be sure the result can only have one record. So most likely you need to add `ORDER BY column LIMIT 1` if `MY_TABLE.UNIQ_COLUMN` not has a unique or primary key